# Creating a function that provides the greatest Fibonacci number that is less than or equal to 'n'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, fibonacci

I am trying to create a function that takes an input 'n' and provides an output which is the highest Fibonacci number that's less than or equal to 'n'. For example, if n = 5, then output is 5. If n = 6, then output is 5.

My solution is workable but it does not seem "efficient" and I am looking for an alternative method. Here is what I did:

```
def fib(n):

    if n<0:
        print("Invalid input")
    x , y = 0 , 1
    while x <= n:
        x , y = y , y + x
    return abs(x-y)
```

I don't think that using abs(x-y) seems very efficient so I would like to ask if anybody has a different way to solving this problem. Thank you.

Comment: Why do you not think that `abs(x-y)` is efficient?

Comment: You'd be hard pressed to find a non-trivial function that's more efficient than `abs`.

Comment: @ArdaArslan: We're finding fibonacci numbers, not primes.

Comment: @ArdaArslan who said anything about primes?

Comment: SInce `y` will always be greater than `x`, it's more efficient to not use `abs` at all.

Comment: Why don't you compare against y, then return x? At any rate, I don't think you'll get much more faster than you already are without switching to another language.

Comment: You might want to use a callable object. Then it is quite easy to store the the fibonacci number you have generated in a cache. Then you won't need to generate them over and over again. Only when you specify a number greater than you have ever used before.

Answer (score 0):

```
def fib(n):
    if n<0:
        print("Invalid input")
    x , y = 0 , 1
    while x <= n:
        x , y = y , y + x
    return y - x
```

Answer (score 0):

This Solution for your question

```
def fib(n):
    x, y = 0, 1
    while True:
        x, y = y , x + y
        if x > n:
            return y-x
```

with this you get correct answer